# How do I create 3D preview in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a web application to customize products. I'm using fabric.js, It's working good. Now i'm looking for 3D Preview link http://printio.ru/mugs/new. I don't know how to implement on my application. Please help me with suggestions and examples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 3d support in fabricjs. you can anyway explore the three.js library and get a webgl 3d image of your object.

This object will be represented on a canvas element backed by three.js.

once you set up this, you can display that canvas element, considering it as a fabric.Image element.

if you need yo to apply custom artwork on the 3d object what you can do is work on three.js and use the interactivity of fabric.js to create the textures for it.

Is difficult to be more technical, i think that regarding fabricjs those are all the options you have.

Comment: Hi AndreaBogazzi, Thanks for your answer. Can i have sample programmatic code.?